# SQL request from Python code takes too much time while executes in 5-6 second from SQL client

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

Facing issue that I can't understand.
Developing python app that stores 10k-60k rows in few tables of database using bulk inserts. After that need to execute following query:

```
        SELECT prev.id
        FROM etldb2.bill as cur
        JOIN (
            SELECT id, identity
            FROM etldb2.bill
            WHERE bill.upload_meta_id IN (1) and bill.status = 1
        ) as prev ON cur.identity = prev.identity
        WHERE upload_meta_id = 2001
```

here I get list of IDs for previous uploads to database.
The problem is that this query takes about 6 minutes (!) while it takes 6 seconds on execution from SQL client (datagrip) same time with stuck query executed from Python code.
No matter whether I am using sessions:

```
bill_ids = session.execute(query_bill_id).all()
```

or not:

```
        with self.engine.connect() as conn:
        bill_ids = conn.execute(query_bill_id)
```

Another weird thing I can't understand is that if I get a sleep for 120 seconds before executing the query it passes in few milliseconds!

```
        sleep(120)
        with self.engine.connect() as conn:
            bill_ids = conn.execute(query_bill_id)
```

So what is this and how can I get request execution faster?

Comment: Is there any way you can trace/profile the 6 minute command? is the database / sql server actually executing the query for six minutes?

Comment: Sounds  like a lock.